# Why was there a sharp increase in the margin of support of independence in Scotland in August/September 2014?

Tags: public-opinion, secession, scotland

Why was there a sharp increase in the **margin** of support of independence in Scotland in August/September 2014?

[image]

(*[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_independence_referendum,_2014#Opinion_polling)*)

Comment: No, it is within the margin of error. A single poll tells you nothing. We need to repeated polls showing the same thing.

Comment: @user1873 - unless  I'm mistaken, the squares represent separate polls. So there's a very clear long term trend since mid-August

Comment: @Avi Oh yeah, me too, you have no idea - I couldn't sleep for weeks because I was dying to know the answer to this question.

Comment: @Shahar you're on a politics SE. You're likely to find people here who really do care about politics.

Comment: @DVK - I looked at [the most recent version of that graphic](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Recent_opinion_polls_for_Scottish_Independence_Referendum.svg#mediaviewer/File:Recent_opinion_polls_for_Scottish_Independence_Referendum.svg), and I can't find that crossover point on it.

Comment: Also: http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/scotland-independence-referendum/

Comment: To get a useful answer would require an in-depth look at each specific poll, and then further analysis from there.  The specific poll results are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_Scottish_independence_referendum,_2014

Comment: That same poll timeline indicates that the most significant jump occurred after the Salmond/Darling debate, but further research would have to be done to link that to the rise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any answer to this question will inevitably be somewhat speculative. However I think there were two main factors:

- The approaching referendum, meaning that previously undecided people started picking a side. Many seem to have come down on the "Yes" side.
- The second Salmond/Darling debate, which Salmond was widely viewed as having won.

It also seems likely, given that the final referendum result was 45-55 whereas the preceding  opinion polls were [more like 47-53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_Scottish_independence_referendum,_2014) if you ignore the undecideds, that there was a degree of polling error.